# Could not find read_audience_network_insights permission during app review

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-audience-network

[image: Permission and Feature]I am making an Audience Network app to show Facebook ads data like **impression** for this my app needs to allow **read_audience_network_insights** permission by users when a user press **Login with facebook** button but before that, I need to send **read_audience_network_insights** permission for review to Facebook to work further.
But unfortunately, there is no **read_audience_network_insights** permission for review in **Permission and Features** under **App Review**.

I have tried to request **read_insights** permission which also does same work as **read_audience_network_insights** during app review but unfortunately, Facebook has rejected this for review.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reply from the app review team:

*The alert for read_audience_network_insights was an error, you should not need to take any further action on your end.*

It is likely that you should not do anything with the alert.